# Can I connect a hardware wallet to Bitcoin Core using HWI?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, hardware-wallet

Presumably HWI on github.com is to do with creating a hardware wallet interface with Bitcoin Core. Am I correct?

What stage is development at presently?

Will one be able to connect a hardware wallet to Bitcoin Core with this interface?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can connect an external signer to Bitcoin Core. You can either use HWI (Hardware Wallet Interface), which is developed by Bitcoin Core developers but currently considered experimental, or use a compatible script if one is provided by your hardware wallet vendor.

To use the external signer feature, start bitcoind with the parameter:

```
$ bitcoind -signer=<path/to/hwi.py>
```

Or if you use the Bitcoin Core GUI, you can fill in the "External signer script path" field in the "Wallet" tab.

Some relevant links:

- [Bitcoin Core external signer documentation](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/external-signer.md)
- [HWI documentation](https://hwi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: And by connecting my hardware wallet to bitcoin core, what will that allow me do?

Comment: @EoinMcQuinn What wallets normally allow you to do, that is receive and send transactions.